# Multiple if's in JavaScript to do multiple things

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div, containing 3 different divs.

I need help to make an intelligent toggle function.

So, when the parent div is clicked, it will check which div is visible, and have a specific action for each div.

So if Div1 is visible, do X
if Div2 is visible, do Y
if div3 is visible, do Z

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  if ($('.div1', this).is(':visible')) {
    $(".div1", this).hide();
    $(".div2", this).show();
  }
  if ($('.div2', this).is(':visible')) {
    $(".div2", this).hide();
    $(".div3", this).show();
    $(".divtemp", this).show();
  }
  if ($('.div3', this).is(':visible')) {
    $(".div3", this).hide();
    $(".div1", this).show();
    $(".divtemp", this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="divtemp"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is, when this code is run, it correctly runs through the whole code because each "if" is fulfilling the next "if".

This is probably basic programming, but if anyone could help it would be highly appreciated!

- S

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, simple `else if`s should do the trick : `if(...){...}else if(...)...`

Comment: I added html aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can cache the DOM elements instead of diving into DOM again and again
2. Use `else if` for exclusive conditions
3. Use multiple selector when you want to perform same function on multiple elements

See comments inline in the code

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var self = this, // Cache
    div1 = $('.div1', self), // Cache
    div2 = $('.div2', self), // Cache
    div3 = $('.div3', self), // Cache
    divtemp = $('.divtemp', self); // Cache

  if (div1.is(':visible')) {
    div1.hide();
    div2.show();
  } else if (div2.is(':visible')) { // Use else if
    div2.hide();
    div3.show();
    divtemp.show();
  } else if (div3.is(':visible')) { // Use else if
    div1.show();
    div3.hide();
    divtemp.hide()
  }
});
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNgvwV

I made a codepen of an example, but I can't get divtemp to show as it is not a child of the button, but a sibling. Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: @StianBakken Use `siblings()` method to select siblings of an element, pass the selector `siblings('.divtemp')`

Comment: I'm so new to coding... Can you give me an example? :) Thank you!

Comment: @StianBakken Use `divtemp = $(this).siblings('.time_container'); // Cache` Check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvNbEQ

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understood what you want, you probably just have to add the "else" clauses. The most important thing, however is that you have to handle click event, and you're doing it wrong.

```
$(".button").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this way you prevent the default click actions;
    if($(".div1").is(":visible")){
        //Do stuff
    }else if $(".div2").is(":visible"){
        //Do other stuff
    }else if(){}
    ...
})
```